# random p tag in advanced custom fields?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

On this page, http://www.sandfordparkslido.org.uk/events-5/ and others. I created a custom field, with advanced custom fields, so that the user can fill the content of the sidebar themselves without leaving the wordpress page they are working on.

The content of the sidebar is then pulled in with `<?php the_field("sidebar_content"); ?>`.

This works fine, however, I am getting some paragraph tags at the start and end of the code? This makes everything sit out of place ever so slightly, hence I want to get rid of them?

Question is, where are they coming from, so that I can delete them?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with WordPress's `wpautop()` filter. 
Here's what ACF says to do: https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/removing-paragraph-tags-from-wysiwyg-fields/

> This is a normal WP behaviour – to turn all new lines into paragraph
>   tags.
>
> To remove this, you can try loading the value without any formatting.
>   You can do this by providing a ‘false’ for the format parameter in the
>   get_field / the_field funcions like so:
>
> the_field('wysiwyg_field', false, false);
>
> Hope that helps.

So just change your line to:

`<?php the_field("sidebar_content", false, false); ?>`

**Update:**
I see further down in that thread they actually say you can just remove the filter with this line:

`remove_filter ('acf_the_content', 'wpautop');`

Comment: Hi, thanks, add, remove_filter ('acf_the_content', 'wpautop'); to function.php?

Comment: Hmm, I've tried both and all suggestions, neither seem to work. Even though I agree they should.

Comment: Maybe try adding a priority > 10? `remove_filter ('acf_the_content', 'wpautop', 20);` Also if you're using a dynamic sidebar, the widget might have an option for auto-formatting.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any block formatting in the field use `false`. It will still allow spans inside:

```
<?php the_field("sidebar_content", false, false); ?>
```

If you want to allow only specific tags in template, like breaks, you may use this code:

```
<?php 
            // remove tags except span and br
            $top_title = get_field('top_title_plus');
            $formatted_top_title = strip_tags( $top_title, '<span><br>');

            if( $formatted_top_title ) : ?>
                <h1 class="entry-title"><?php echo $formatted_top_title; ?></h1>
            endif; ?>
```